# How to remove computer in AD and email the computers that were removed to yourself

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to remove a list of machines from AD that are in a txt file. I have no issue getting them removed. However once they are removed, I want PowerShell to email my group saying these machines were removed from AD. Can anyone provide some help?

I have tried If, try, and statements but cant seem to get it working.

```
Get-Content 'c:\temp\Remove AD Computers.txt' | % { Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq $_ } } | Remove-ADObject -Recursive -Whatif

$Computerlist = Get-Content 'c:\temp\Remove AD Computers.txt'

ForEach($Computer in $Computerlist)
{ 
   try{
        Get-ADComputer $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        $output = "$Computer still exsists in AD."
}
   catch{
   $output = "$Computer has been removed from AD." 
}
}
Write-Host $output

Send-MailMessage -From 'ADComputersRemoved@redgold.com' -To 'support@redgold.com' -Subject 'AD Computers removed' -Body "$output" -SmtpServer smtp.domain.com
```

I need this to remove the computer and then email me the results of the removal. Hope this is enough information. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Hi! you need one email with all computer list or need one email by action?

Comment: I need one email that list all computers that were successfully removed.

Comment: I don't see any logic here that is trying to send an email. Have you tried something yet like `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: @Matt I apologize, I should have specified a little more. The removing of the object and sending the email I have working. I just cannot get it to send me the results of the removal. Below is my full line of code.

Comment: This might just be me but I don't understand what you are expecting to see that you are not if the removal and the email works. Should there be information on the console you mean? `Write-Host $output` is not inside your `for` loop which I suppose is your problem since you would only see the last one.

Comment: @Matt When the Write-Host $output was running I was only seeing one machine. Now that it's in the for loop it works good. One more problem though. When I receive the email. I get the very last line and not all of the data. Why?

Comment: @Matt For example I am trying to remove D001234, D007890, D009876. I will only get in an email that D009876 has been removed from AD.

Comment: That is because you are overwriting `$output` every time you iterate through your loop. So you only get the last result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your foreach loop like the following, you will have all of your computers in the list. Each loop iteration will add an indexed element to the `$output` array with a value of one of your two strings.

```
$output = ForEach($Computer in $Computerlist)
{ 
   try{
        Get-ADComputer $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
        "$Computer still exsists in AD."
}
   catch{
   "$Computer has been removed from AD." 
}
}
```

Since `$output` will be an array of strings, you will need to make that a string when you pass it into the `-body` parameter of `Send-MailMessage`. I used the `-join` operator with CRLF characters. You can use whatever you like. `$output | out-string` will accomplish something similar.

```
Send-MailMessage -From 'ADComputersRemoved@redgold.com' -To 'support@redgold.com' -Subject 'AD Computers removed' -Body ($output -join "`r`n") -SmtpServer smtp.redgold.com
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the help it is much appreciated. I love powershell but sometimes it just takes some outside knowledge to get things working haha :)